# How do you map a base class using ColdFusion ORM?

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have two components, a base `Entity` component:

```
<cfcomponent persistent="true">
    <cfproperty name="Id" fieldtype="id" generator="native">
</cfcomponent>
```

And a `Client` component that extends it:

```
<cfcomponent persistent="true" extends="Entity">
    <cfproperty name="FirstName">
    <cfproperty name="LastName">
</cfcomponent>
```

However, when I try to create an instance of `Client`, I get an error that says that they're being mapped as two different tables. I know Hibernate has the ability to ignore a base class, but how would I do it with ColdFusion's tags, or do I have to fall back to HBM mappings for this feature?

Addendum: Removing the `persistent="true"` from `Entity` doesn't work either, `Client` will act as if it doesn't have an `Id` property if I do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your base "Entity" class try removing persistent="true" and adding mappedSuperClass="true".

```
<cfcomponent mappedSuperClass="true">
    <cfproperty name="Id" fieldtype="id" generator="native">
</cfcomponent>
```

You need to have applied the 9.0.1 update to ColdFusion.

Comment: Make sure you ORMReload() after making the changes.